# Pyinstaller- Including assets in executable

Tags: pyinstaller

Cant figure out how to pack custom resources into my executable, i found this bit of info,https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/pyinstaller/HcTTyFlPJHA/kqd4wnm7JhkJ

My assets folder holds images for a tkinter GUI,"assets\images.png". Something id like to include in the executable itself.

So i included this line under "a.datas,"in my .spec file.

Tree('assets', prefix='assets\'),

Then repacked with PyInstaller "pyinstaller.py MipMapper-V1.2\MipMapper-V1.2.spec". This produces an exe that does not have the assets included. I can copy the assets folder to the exe's directory and it works. Is it my code? it refers to "assets\" a relative path for things. So i get a -1 return error. It cannot find the assets. Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Adding data files](http://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/#adding-data-files) and next section [using data files from module](http://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/#using-data-files-from-a-module) in pyinstaller docs.

Yes, you should to use package relative path instead of plain relative in your code. Because package will be extracted not relative to execution binary, but somewhere in temp dir. Look for `pkg_resources` package. For example this function:

```
dir = resource_filename('your_package', 'app/samples')
```

To clarify how to define datas in spec look for example:

```
a = Analysis(['../trunk/__main__.py']
         ...
         datas=[('../src/trunk/your_package/app/samples/data.bin', 'your_package/app/samples')],
         ...
```

Comment: FWIW, the links have changed since 2016, now the doc is here : https://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/spec-files.html#adding-files-to-the-bundle

Comment: @rotoglup moved again to https://pyinstaller.org/en/stable/spec-files.html#adding-files-to-the-bundle