# python pyinstaller bundle image in GUI to onefile EXE?

Tags: python, tkinter, exe, photo

I've successfully created an EXE file from python tkinter GUI which includes images. see the following code:

```
lblLogo=Label(main)
lblLogo.grid(row=3,column=11,rowspan=4)

try:
    filelocation="C:/Documents/Python/ScreenPartNumberProgram/"
    KasonLogo=PhotoImage(file=filelocation+"KasonLogo.png")
    KasonLogo=KasonLogo.zoom(25,20)
    KasonLogo=KasonLogo.subsample(50,50)
    lblLogo.config(image=KasonLogo)
    icon=PhotoImage(file=filelocation+"KasonLogo.png")
    main.tk.call('wm','iconphoto',main._w,icon)
except:
    print("warning: could not load photos")
    lblLogo.config(text="[KasonLogo.png]")
```

the exe file opens and works perfectly on my computer. I used this command to get the .exe:

```
pyinstaller --onefile --noconsole myscript.py
```

The only problem is this file requires the image to be in the same folder or it doesn't show on the label. How can I get the image bundled into the EXE without requiring an external file?

Thanks in advance

edit:
I looked at the links provided,did more research, and still haven't solved the issue. The program works only if the image is in the same folder. I'd really like to make it work without requiring an external image file. the resource_path technique doesn't seem to work for me either...

I also tried modifying my code to use PIL's ImageTk and same issue. program loads image only if the external image file is in the folder with it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pyinstaller- Including assets in executable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36555088/pyinstaller-including-assets-in-executable)

Comment: Hello,
thanks for the reply. I udnerstand the program requires an outside image file but is there a way to not require the external file? I feel there must be a way to pack the image into the EXE

Answer (score 7, accepted):

HOLY COW ! After a few more days of headaches I FINALLY found an approach that works... here is what I did to get the program to work without requiring an external image file:

step 1: encode the image file (note that it must be a GIF. you can convert it using paint):

```
import base64
with open("MyPicture.gif", "rb") as image_file:
    encoded_string = base64.b64encode(image_file.read())
print(encoded_string)#print string to copy it (see step 2)
```

step 2: the next step is to copy and paste the string into a separate myimages.py file and 
store it as variable. for example:

```
imageString = b'R0lGODlhyADIAPcAAAA .....blah blah really long string.......'
```

step 3: then import the myimages.py into main program and call the variable

```
from myimages import *
pic=imageString#GIF decoded to string. imageString from myimages.py
render = PhotoImage(data=pic)
myLabel.config(image=render)
```

step 4: in the spec file: include the myimages.py as data

```
# -*- mode: python -*-

block_cipher = None

#instructions: pyinstaller --onefile --noconsole myProgram.spec

file_name = 'myProgram'
add_files=[('myimages.py','module')]

a = Analysis([file_name+'.py'],
             pathex=['C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Python36-32\\Scripts'],
             binaries=[],
             datas=add_files,
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=exclude_list,
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          a.binaries,
          a.zipfiles,
          a.datas,
          name=file_name,
          debug=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          runtime_tmpdir=None,
          console=False )
```

step 5: finally you can compile to EXE:

```
pyinstaller --onefile --noconsole myProgram.spec
```

*SIGH* If anyone has a better solution, please post it here. until then I'm glad something works...

Comment: I'm having the same issue. What's your myLabel variable referencing ? Is that the tkinter label?

Comment: This is a cool solution. I feel like there has to be a more legitimate way to do it though

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same issue when I was wanting to include a .ico file to use as the icon for my tkinter app. Here's how I got it to work:

1. When building the .exe file with PyInstaller, I specified the --add-data option with the full path to my .ico.
2. When the app starts up, it has to unpack everything from the .exe in a temp directory, so I get the path to that temp directory and use it to specify the temp location of my .ico file.

Before the mainloop is kicked off, and using 'tempfile' to get the temp file directory and 'glob' to check for a file pattern match:

```
tempdir = tempfile.gettempdir()
icon_path = tempdir + '\\' + 'next_subdirectory_pattern' + '\\' + '*.ico'
icon_matches = glob.glob(icon_path)
if len(icon_matches) > 0:
    logo = icon_matches[0]
else:
    logo = ''
tk.Tk.iconbitmap(self, default=logo)
```

Probably not the most eloquent way to do it, but it works.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I did it...

**To bundle the image with the executable:**

Use the following command to save your icon to a folder called "icon" that will be generated in the "C:\Users<username>\AppData\Local\Temp_MEI123456" folder generated by pyinstaller at runtime:

```
--add-data=C:\absolute\path\to\your\ICON.ico;icon
```

My full command line, the string I type into the python terminal (i'm using pycharm IDE) to generate my EXE, looks like this:

```
pyinstaller -w -F -i=C:\absolute\path\to\your\ICON.ico --add-data=C:\absolute\path\to\your\ICON.ico;icon -n=MyEXEsNameV1 main.py
```

(For debug it is helpful to omit -w and add --debug=all)

*doc reference: https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html#options-group-what-to-bundle-where-to-search*

**To access the image in my python script main.py:**

I used the following code to setup the tk window:

```
import tkinter as tk
from os import path

    # main widget
    self.root = tk.Tk(master)
    self.root.title('Window Title Bar Name V1.0')
    self.root.minsize(1234, 1234)

    # get icon
    try:
        # Get the absolute path of the temp directory
        path_to_icon = path.abspath(path.join(path.dirname(__file__), 'icon/GAUGE-ICON.ico')) 
        # set the icon of the tk window
        self.root.iconbitmap(path_to_icon)
    except:
        pass
```

*doc reference: https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/runtime-information.html*

Answer (score 0):

In addition to accepted answer I want to add modified version:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

from res import *
#res is a module with your base64 image string and in my case variable is icon_base64
from base64 import b64decode

pic_as_bytes=ImageTk.BytesIO(icon_base64)
my_image=Image.open(pic_as_bytes)
```

Please note this code will work in Python3, but could not in Python2 cause it needs differrent aproach and more conversions (the link below has exactly an example for Python2).

For more info please refer to https://github.com/Ariel-MN/Tkinter_base64_Images/blob/master/tkinter_base64_image-ico.py

Answer (score 0):

I tried the following methods. The 2nd option worked for me.

1. Use the command you mentioned to generate exe and copy the exe file into the source folder of your project (Where the python file is).
2. I fix it using [auto-py-to-exe](https://pypi.org/project/auto-py-to-exe/) which uses pyinstaller. There you
   can see the command generated.

   ```
   pyinstaller --noconfirm --onedir --windowed --add-data "path/assets/"  "path/gui.py"
   ```

   First, try using `--onefile` instead of `--onedir`. Mine didn't work
   when I used `--onefile`. So I had to covert `--onedir`.

Answer (score 0):

I solve a similar issue: I could not get the images in my pyinstaller genated package.

But in fact, they were included in a subdirectory with same name as the images.

In stead of:

```bash
pyinstaller [...] --add-data "logo.png:logo.png"
```

I had to:

```bash
pyinstaller [...] --add-data "logo.png:."
```

Then this example worked for me (note: `logo.png` not provided):

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
"""
REM Bundle using:
pyinstaller --onefile ^
   test.py ^
   --noconfirm --nowindow --windowed ^
   --add-data "logo.png:."
"""

import os
import sys
import tkinter as tk

IS_BUNDLED = hasattr(sys, "_MEIPASS")
BUNDLE_DIR = getattr(
    sys, "_MEIPASS", os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
)

IMAGE_PATH = "logo.png"


mainWindow = tk.Tk()

imagepath = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(BUNDLE_DIR, IMAGE_PATH))
img = tk.PhotoImage(file=imagepath)
tk.Label(mainWindow, image=img).grid(column=0, row=0)

mainWindow.mainloop()
```

I discovered this by looking in the bundle directory (`%_MEIPASS%`) where I disovered that the image paths were directories.

Possibly there is no need to use "BUNDLE_DIR" in the above, but it worked for me as is, and it may be a good hint for some readers.

Answer (score 0):

If you apply @jaredmt's answer, you can think of this method.

First, extract the binary data of the image.

```
with open("something.png", 'rb') as f:
    image_blob = f.read()
print(image_blob)
```

Then something like this will be output.

```
b'\x89PNG\r\n\x1a\n\x00\x00\...blah blah really long string....
```

Copy this and assign it to a variable. Or create a function that returns this:

If given to a variable

```
image_byte=b'\x89PNG\r\n\x1a\n\x00\x00\...blah blah really long string....
```

If you create a function

```
def image_binary():
    return b'\x89PNG\r\n\x1a\n\x00\x00\x00\rIHDR\x...blah blah really long string....
```

Install and load the required libraries. `pip install pillow`

```
import io
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
```

And you can use it.

```
root = tk.Tk()
image_byte=image_binary() # or image_byte=b'\x89PNG\r\n\x1a\n\x00\x00\...blah blah 
image = Image.open(io.BytesIO(image_byte))
b = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
label = tk.Label(root, image=b)
label.pack()
root.mainloop()
```